# How do you specify facts in prolog files?

Tags: prolog

I have a few facts stored in a file test.pl.

```
memory(0, 0, 0).
memory(0, 1, 0).
memory(0, 2, 0).
```

Now in the same directory, I start gprolog and load the file.

```
| ?- ['test.pl'].
compiling /home/cib/projects/prolog/test.pl for byte code...
/home/cib/projects/prolog/test.pl compiled, 3 lines read - 501 bytes written, 5 ms

yes
```

But it will treat the loaded facts strangely. Trying to query one of them:

```
| ?- memory(0, 1, 0).

true ? h
Action (; for next solution, a for all solutions, RET to stop) ? ;

no
```

It's like it's trying to list some unifications, only there are no variables to unify. If I specify the facts with [user], there's no problem.

```
| ?- [user].
compiling user for byte code...
memory(0, 1, 0).

user compiled, 2 lines read - 229 bytes written, 10237 ms
warning: user:1: redefining procedure memory/3
         /home/cib/projects/prolog/test.pl:1: previous definition

yes
| ?- memory(0, 1, 0).

yes
```

I really don't know what's going on. I've tried to look for some definitions of how file loading works and how it's different from the interpreter on google, but to no avail.

Comment: If you enter all three of your facts under `[user].` you will actually get the same behavior as using the file `['test.pl']`. So the behavior is related to there being more than one fact asserted for `memory` and it's consistent across different ways of asserting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider what the warning means: it's replacing *all* the facts, then when you query `?- memory(0,1,0).` there are no alternatives to search.

Then you get `yes`, instead of `true` you get when there *could* be more solutions.

Seems indeed that gprolog compute just first argument indexing, and since in the first scenario there are more facts with 0 as first argument, it reasonably wait for your choice.

You can verify the database content issuing a `?- listing(memory).`

Comment: Ahh, didn't think of that! Thanks. I'm not familiar with the /3 syntax yet, so I didn't realize it meant all 3 definitions were being replaced. Alright, so my original question is based on false assumptions - The thing confusing me is actually always true(why does it think there could be more solutions when of the 3, only one matches exactly my query?).

Comment: Actually, matching *can* be a rather complex operations, and by design Prolog algorithm *must* try to match (unify) any possible clause. Any modern Prolog implementation has first argument indexing, meaning that in simple cases the engine can actually 'jump' to the first matching one. But all three clauses are equally indexed in your case.